# Align Asp.net Buttons under GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface

I have a GridView with three buttons under it.  I am trying to figure out how to align them so the first button's left edge is aligned with the left edge of the GridView, the second button is centered under the GridView, and the third button's right edge is aligned with the right edge of the GridView.  If the GridView's width expands, I am wanting the buttons to stay aligned with the GridView.  Right now, the buttons are "clumped" together horizontally, aligned to the left.
Here is a rough sketch of what I'm wanting.

[image: .]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about put the Gridview and Buttons in seperate rows of a Table?

Here is an example with inline styles:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="width: 100%">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ShowHeader="false">
                 ...
            </asp:GridView>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 33%; text-align: left">
            <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center">
            <asp:Button ID="button2" runat="server" />
        </td>
         <td style="width: 33%; text-right">
            <asp:Button ID="button3" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Maybe you could try adding some padding-left or padding-right to some of the styles

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways  you can do that. You can put the buttons into the Footer of the grid or put a big div or table under the grid that is the same width as your grid.

I would put them in the footer template like so: (pseudo)

```
div width 100%
   div  33%
     button 1 (align it to left)
   div 33%
     button 2 (align it to center
   div 33%
     button 3 (align it to right
```

You can use fixed sizes if you know them

**Edit:**
Just noticed the big gap under the grid, you can put it like this

```
div 100%
   grid  (assuming 100% also)
   div  (100%)
     and div 33% with buttons go here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try witht this code

```
<FooterTemplate>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td class=""><asp:Button ID="Btn1" runat="server" Text="Btn1"/>
          </td> 
          <td class=""><asp:Button ID="Btn2" runat="server" Text="Btn2"/>
          </td> 
          <td class=""><asp:Button ID="Btn3" runat="server" Text="Btn3"/>
          </td> 
      </tr>
  </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

You can add style property to your cell of table

```
text-align: center;

text-align: left;

text-align: right;
```